# How to deallocate all allocated memory in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Not sure if this is possible, but nonetheless.

I have a large Fortran90 code (not written by me) that I wish to run with python and mpi4py. Rather than spawn multiple instances of the Fortran executable I would like to spawn once, and loop through the program multiple times. This is something that I have done previously, and works well. However this Fortran code is fairly sprawling, and quite complicated vs previous codes I have tackled with this approach.

My question is - is there a simple way of tearing down and deallocating all allocated arrays from inside the program at the end of each loop (without me having to go through the whole code and ensure everything has been deallocated by hand). At present if I loop through the main body of the code it errors on the second pass through the loop, because it tries to allocate an already allocated array.

Comment: Depending on how the Fortran code needs to be called, perhaps automatic deallocation on end program could be used?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no deallocate all command that would deallocate all allocatable entities in the program. You have to maintain any such list yourself and deallocate it yourself.

You can make use of the automatic deallocation in Fortran, but that only works for local variables. Not for entities in modules or in the main program.

Comment: What I thought - and exactly what I didn't want to hear. Guess I may make myself a strong coffee and get to it.